# CKEditor 4.2 and Media Module, Has anyone gotten this to work?

Tags: wysiwyg, media

Been trying to create a working mix of these modules and only seem to succeed if CKEDitor is using version 4.0.3 or lower.

Any insight here would be huge. Thanks!

Comment: In my experience the `WYSIWYG` module helps alot here. Not just install the `ckeditor + media` modules but the `wysiwyg + ckeditor as a library + media` module ... I haven't tried those version numbers persay. I dont see why it wouldnt work.

Answer (score 1):

CKEditor 4.1 introduced a feature called [Advanced Content Filter](http://docs.ckeditor.com/#!/guide/dev_advanced_content_filter). It might be stripping some code. You can test if it's the cause by adding this code your ckeditor/config.js file:

```
CKEDITOR.config.allowedContent = true
```

Granted, you shouldn't just leave it *true*, but it will give you an idea if that's the problem.